# adding an anchor tag with image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created an image tag in JQuery. Now I need to add one more anchor tag with it. How can I implement it with JavaScript?

I tried this:

```
var imgg = document.createElement("img");
imgg.className='myclass';
$( ".myclass" ).add( "<a href="#">Test</a>" );
```

but it isn't working. It should appear as:

```
  <img src=""><a href="#"></a>
```

Which function should I use to add one more anchor tag within `img` tag?

Comment: usually its the opposite you want `<a href="#"><img src=""></a>`

Comment: If you want double quotes in a double-quoted string, you need to escape them. I'm sure your console must show you some error messages. Also, consider attaching the node you create somewhere in the DOM.

Comment: no i want it exactly like i have written .

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$("<img>").addClass("myclass").after("<a href='#'></a>").appendTo("body");
```